# phonegap localstorage saves after power off?

Tags: cordova, local-storage

Does data saved via localstorage in phonegap remains retained even after the app/phone is turn off and restarted? If not, should I be using sqlite instead?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, but you are actually using HTML5 web storage (great write-up [here](http://www.diveintohtml5.net/)) to store the persistent data, not phonegap.

I wrote a [tutorial](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt4p3) on using local storage (on PhoneGap / Android). If you're not interested in the full tutorial, search the page for "localStorage" and "JSON" (for parse() and stringify()) for examples of their use.

Answer (score 2):

phonegap 1.4.1 on android 2.3 (api level 8) does not persist data either by localStorage or websql through a phone power off/on cycle. renders it useless. trying file api instead.